# Any reason why map function would not be working inside presentational component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Can someone help me figure out why the map function in my component is not running? I get some data from firebase and iterate over it, pushing each item (song) into my container components state (an array). I then pass that array down to my presentational component. I console.log in the presentational component to make sure it gets there which you can see from the screen shots it does. But for whatever reason map isn't running on the array so nothing shows up on the screen. I'm sure its an array and I'm sure it has the map method available on it. Literally no idea why it's not running at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Here is the full code for the presentational component

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem } from 'native-base';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function SongList (props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {console.log(props.availableSongs)}
      {props.availableSongs.map((song) => {
        console.log(song)
        return <Text>{song.songName}</Text>
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

SongListPropTypes = {
  availableSongs: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 140
  }
})

export default SongList;
```

And its parent component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { db } from '~/config/firebase';
import SongList from './SongList';

class SongListContainer extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    uid: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      availableSongs: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    const ref = db.ref(`users/${this.props.uid}/availableTracks/`);

    ref.once('value', (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        const song = childSnapshot.val();

        this.setState(() => {
          availableSongs: this.state.availableSongs.push(song)
        })
      });
    });
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <SongList availableSongs={this.state.availableSongs}/>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps ({authentication}) {
  return {
    uid: authentication.uid
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SongListContainer);
```

Comment: Have you verified `song.songName` exists?

Comment: When I try `console.log(props.availableSongs[0]);` I get `undefined`....But why

Comment: Can I see how you render `SongList`?

Comment: @AndrewLi Updated with parent component.

Comment: I don't think your code can even 'compile', is `SongListPropTypes`(not `SongList.propTypes`) a typo?

Comment: From the console....`Warning: View.propTypes has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version of ReactNative. Use ViewPropTypes instead.`

Comment: @maxwellgover your `setState` in componentDidMount has slight issue, return value of `this.state.availableSongs.push(song)` is the array length not the array, use the `array spread` syntax instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the state wont get updated immediately once u call setState but the render method will be called before the value is set to state.

This happens particularly because there is a fetch call from firebase going on there.

A simple workaround here would be adding a callback to your `setState()`

```
 yourFunction(){
  this.setState(() => {
      availableSongs: this.state.availableSongs.push(song)
    }, this.updateStateFunction); 
   }  
 updateStateFunction(){
   this.props.updateStateFunction(this.state)
 }
```

Something like this should work.